# 'Failed to fetch' when trying to upgrade using terminal

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-elser/winelol/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-elser/winelol/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu? Could you post all the output of your terminal please? Have you tried with the procedures mentioned in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

I would of thought that the PPA errors could not be obtained as they could possibly be outdated or some other issue as they cannot be located.

According to [this website](http://blog.launchpad.net/ppa/failed-to-fetch-errors-for-ppas) you can fix these errors by using `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` to edit the sources list file. Once you are in the sources file you can search for the PPA sources and check if they have been setup incorrectly for some reason.

If this fails you can also try `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and then check the individual files from there using a text editor (I prefer using `nano` for this).

I have not used these methods before so I am not too sure if they would fix your problem. These methods seem like they will just check if someone has done some editing to the sources or added the sources incorrectly, I am not too sure what else you could do to fix the problem if the above methods fail.

I hope these suggestions help you.

Comment: i did the first suggestion and some files says Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: Ok, I can't give you too much help as I don't have that much experience with these types of problems. Try having a quick look over https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure for more help.

Comment: If this problem still occurs after you have tried every method you have come across I guess you will have to wait for the packages to be supported and come back online.

Comment: just one more thing whats the site u send for? trbleshooting

Comment: Some helpful link http://community.ubuntu.com/help-information/. Report bugs at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs. I'm sure that people have already submitted the same bug as you though so you probably don't need to worry about it. If any of these helped you, you can mark my reply as an answer.

Comment: You could also try reading through http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa?lq=1 for a more detailed guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is caused because the software sources that allow your computer to download updates and other softwares are not set properly.

You might want to open **Ubuntu Software Center**, go to **Edit -> Software Sources** and try changing/adding the *ppas* from where you are currently downloading the updates. You might also try changing the *server* from where ubuntu tries to install the updates by default.

As far as the 404 error you receive here is concerned. The ppa you are using doesn't currently host any packages for raring. Check this [link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-elser/winelol/ubuntu/dists/).